# Same background between view controllers in Xamarin IOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

How can i do this in xamarin ios:

I have 3 view controllers, the first controller have only 2 buttons, Login and Register with the background of the view, how can i do when the user press any button, go to another viewcontroller with animation (move bottom to top the content) with a fixed background? now i have the background move's with the buttons,

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can 1 view controller & just use scrollview & 3 view to move the background.
Make sure your scrollview not bounce & pagingEnable = true. 
Use HandleScrolled to move the background view with changing the background view frame.X

Comment: not a pretty solution no? i was wondering in something like put a background in the navigationController but it only works in the first view

Comment: your background will be imageview behind your other view.